# Largest number among the given numbers

Tags: number-theory, numerical-methods

How to find the largest number among the following numbers.

$(a)\;3^{210}$

$(b)\;7^{140}$

$(c)\;17^{105}$

$(d)\;31^{84}$

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What are you allowed to use ?

Comment: Binomials, number theory

Comment: Compare them with $2^{420}$.

Comment: But i want to know how to judge that it should be compare with $2^{420}$

Comment: All of the bases are one less or one greater than a power of $2$. The exponents are such that you always have $(2^k \pm 1)^e$ with $k\cdot e = 420$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align}3^{210}&<4^{210}&=2^{420}\\
7^{140}&<8^{140}&=2^{420}\\
17^{105}&>16^{105}&=2^{420}\\
31^{84}&<32^{84}&=2^{420}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Very nice. +1. .

Answer (score 1):

If you are allowed a calculator, take the logs and compute them.  $\log 3^{210}=210 \log 3$ and so on

If you must do it by hand, you need to be clever.  To compare a and b, note that the exponents are both divisible by $70$, so you are comparing $(3^3)^{70}$ and $(7^2)^{70}$.  You may know $3^3$ and $7^2$, or they are not hard to compute.  Similar techniques will deal with the others.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $.3^{210}=(.3^2)^{105}=.09^{105}<.17^{105}$.
Also $.31^{84}>.17^{84}>.17^{105}$ and
finally $.7^{140}=(.7^2)^{70}=.49^{70}>.31^{70}>.31^{84}$. Hence
$$ .7^{140}> .31^{84}>.17^{105}>.3^{210}$$

Comment: I am so sorry that is not decimal.

Comment: I have edited recently